# Text in comment box

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, user-interface

When I want to type a new comment, there is some text already present in the text box, which disappears when I start typing my comment. However, this text is not complete, and only shows: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like":

[image]

Am I the only one with this bug? For info, it shows both on Safari and Firefox, on Mac OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the issue exactly as you describe it, but I do see the problem in the alt text on the "add comment" link:

> [image: bad alt text]

I'll report this to the SE admins and they can take a look. Thanks!

---

EDIT: It appears they [already know about this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190309/139256) and [it's already been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190351/139256). The fix may take some time to propogate to all sites, so you may not see the changes for a few hours.

Comment: Yep.  No need to post an additional "official" answer because it would be exactly what this one says.